# NSTextAttachment image alignment

Tags: ios, image, sdk, uitextview, nstextattachment

I am following this cool tutorial [Implementing Rich Text with Images on OS X and iOS](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/comment-page-1/#comment-873) by @Duncan Groenewald and was able to display images in my `UITextView`. However, these images are not centered they way I would like them to be. See image

[image: NSTextAttachment sample image]

As you can see, I would like my image to be centered on the X-axis.

I tried returning the `rect` with appropriate values in `-attachmentBoundsForTextContainer:proposedLineFragment:glyphPosition:characterIndex` but that did not help.

I also tried setting the `NSKernAttributeName` for the `NSTextAttachment` attributed string. But all it did was hide the image some how.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the paragraph style on your attachment with a center alignment.

If your images are embedded in an attributed string as attachments, you can access them by enumerating through the attributed string's attachment attributes.
For example:

```
    attributedContent.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, inRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedContent.length), options: nil) { (attribute, range, stop) -> Void in
        if let attachment = attribute as? NSTextAttachment {

            // this example assumes you want to center all attachments. You can provide additional logic here. For example, check for attachment.image.

            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center
            attributedContent.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is **Swift 3.1** using *extension*:

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {

    func setAttachmentsAlignment(_ alignment: NSTextAlignment) {
        self.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.length), options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { (attribute, range, stop) -> Void in
            if attribute is NSTextAttachment {
                let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment
                self.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: range)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this way you can you easily apply alignment for attachments on attributed string:

```
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
// add attachments
attributeString.setAttachmentsAlignment(.center)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way how to set the alignment for an NSTextAttachment image. Hopefully this will also help someone struggling with this. I'm using the code below in a *func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell*

```
var buttonText = "My Button";

let align = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
align.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center;
align.firstLineHeadIndent = 10.0;
align.headIndent = 10.0;
align.tailIndent = -10.0;

let para = NSMutableAttributedString();

// top padding
para.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: align, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]));

// image
let img = NSTextAttachment();
img.image = UIImage(named: "MyIcon");
img.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)!.descender, width: img.image!.size.width, height: img.image!.size.height);
let nas = NSAttributedString(attachment: img).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString;
nas.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: align, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nas.length));
para.append(nas);

// space to text
buttonText = " " + buttonText;

// text
para.append(NSAttributedString(
    string: buttonText,
    attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: align, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]));

// bottom padding
para.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: align, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]));

// set cell label
let label = cell.textLabel!;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.layer.borderWidth = 0;
label.layer.masksToBounds = false;
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
label.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green;
label.attributedText = para;
```